# get posts order by custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

here, i want the post order by custom field(created by plugin Advanced Custom Fields), let say the posts order by the orders(custom field), then the categories with greatest custom field value post will appear first, is it available?
here my code is,

```
$args = array('category' => $cat1->term_id ,
              'meta_key' => 'orders',
              'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
              'order' => 'DESC' ,'numberposts'   => -1 
              );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
$i = 1;
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); 
    echo    get_field('orders',$post->ID);
    $i++;
endforeach;
```

Comment: Please explain more. what have you stored in 'orders' field and this field is repeater , textfield what ? and this field is added on all posts ?

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your code, its really hard to read like this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass 'post_type' =>'post' in $args array. So it will be like

```
$args = array('category' => $cat1->term_id ,
              'post_type' =>'post',
              'meta_key' => 'orders',
              'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
              'order' => 'DESC' ,'numberposts'   => -1 
              );
```

I am assuming that you are passsing post type = post. You can change there it if it's different.